# Exclude files in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.5

I have a script, which recollects in a dictionary the directories, the number of sub-directories and files in it. I need to exclude the files of this dictionary but I am not able to do that.

```
path="/home/tmp"

def PathToDict(path):
    st = os.lstat(path)
    result = {}
    if S_ISDIR(st.st_mode):
        result['Path'] = path
        result['Subdir'] = {
           name: PathToDict(os.path.join(path,name))                       
           for name in os.listdir(path)}
        result['Num_Subdir'] = int(len([i for i, j, k in os.walk(path)]))
```

This is the function which recollects all folders, but the problem is that also recollect files like .sh or logs. I'm trying to use os.path.isdir method but I can't.

Actual output:

```
'Path': '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/updates',
            'Num_Subdir': 8,
            'Subdir': {
                'nextBuildNumber': {},
                'config.xml': {},
                'lastSuccessful': {},
                'lastStable': {},
                'builds': {
                    'Path': '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/updates2',
                    'Num_Subdir': 7,
                    'Subdir': {
                        'lastStableBuild': {},
                        'lastSuccessfulBuild': {},
                        '1': {
                            'Path': '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/updates3',
                            'Num_Subdir': 1,
                            'Subdir': {
                                'changelog.xml': {},
                                'injectedEnvVars.txt': {},
                                'build.xml': {},
                                'changelog.xml.temp2': {},
                                'log': {}
```

And i need the output excluding .xml and .txt for example. In the root of the path, i also have files and they are listed in dictionary and i need to exclude those files too.

Comment: basically, you want all the directory inside the path and no files names?

Comment: Yes, i need that the files that there are in the subdirectories doesnt appear in the dictionary. I only need directories, not files like .sh or .py you know?

Comment: can you write the final output , else this will give you all the `[os.path.abspath(name) for name in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(name)]` list in the path

Comment: @prashantrana if i use your code, i only get the first lvl directory in the output, no the subdirectories, i don't know why...

Comment: can ou provide the output that you desire, in the above case you need to parse it according to your need

Comment: @prashantrana I just update the post with output. Thanks.

Comment: use os.path.isdir(x) for checking whether it's a folder

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import os

# Empty Dictionary that will store the Directory Tree
Directories = {}

# this value will act as a counter for folder key's
i = 0

# Assign your directory location to this variable
rootDir = r'Dir_path'


for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    Directories[str(i)] = dirName
    i += 1

print(Directories)
```

Honestly, I would recommend storing the Dir Paths in a list rather then in a Dictionary, as it makes accessing them a lot easier

Answer (score 0):

This should give you all directories.

```
import os

path = 'path_to_root_dir'

dir_list = []
exclude = ['directory', 'to', 'ignore']
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in exclude]
    for dir in dirs:
        dir_list.append(os.path.join(root,dir))

print(dir_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
path = r'C:\Users\user\Videos\xox'
import os

def fun(path):
    path = path


    lis_of_dir = [ (os.path.join(path,i),i) for i in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path,i))]
    length = len(lis_of_dir)
    sub = [{i[1]:fun(i[0])} for i in lis_of_dir]

    return {'path':path,'no_of_dir':length,'sub_dir':sub}

print(fun(path))
```